# Flash builder, AS3 accessing embed files (compiling issue)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, compiler-construction, flashdevelop, flash-builder4.5

I have a problem when compiling embed files using Flash Builder,

If I have my class called "Testing" with this embed file:

```
[Embed(source = "myfile.xml", mimeType = "application/octet-stream")]
    public static var MyFile:Class;
```

I can access the file by these 2 ways:

```
new Testing.MyFile();
```

or

```
var file:Class = getDefinitionByName("packagename.Testing_MyFile") as Class;

new file();
```

The first one works fine, but the other one doesn't find the class using getDefinitionByName.
I found that the swf doesn't create the object with the name packagename.Testing_MyFile.

Im moving code from FlashDevelop to Flash builder and the first one create those files, do you know if Flash Builder needs a special flag or something to create those file?

Thanks

Comment: I'm really confused by your question.  Why would Flash Builder automatically create a class named Testing_MyFile in a specific package?  Your first approach just uses Object property notation to access the Class variable and build a new instance of it. The second approach tries to access an explicit class which isn't there.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess the second (dynamic) approach would work if you did `var file:Class = getDefinitionByName("packagename.Testing") as Class; new file.MyFile();`. Or maybe even `new file["MyFile"]()` if you want to make it dynamic all the way.